# How to trigger Multibranch job using bash scripting?

Tags: jenkins, triggers, devops

Tried looking for **Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts) option**, but the only option available is **Periodically if not otherwise run**. Need to run trigger multibranch specific job for specific branch using curl from the local machine.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

This should be possible like this:

```
curl -X POST -u <jenkins_user>:<jenkins_secret>  <jenkins_url>/job/<multibranch_pipeline_name>/job/<branch_name>/build
```